# Как настроить UFW на удалённой машине, не сломав SSH?

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, firewall, ufw

Имеется сервер Apache, и нужно настроить UFW Firewall. При `ufw enable` на выход даётся предупреждение о том, что подключения SSH будут прерваны:

```
# ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? n
Aborted
```

Используется машина Google Cloud, к которой можно подключиться только по SSH.

Как настроить UFW так, чтобы не запретить SSH?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `sudo ufw allow ssh` из источника : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru

Comment: можно ещё использовать старый трюк с кроном - просто добавляете в крон (или at) задачу на полное удаление правил. И можно экспериментировать.